# I don't want to be notified by GitHub on new issues

Tags: notifications, github-issues

GitHub watch notifies me about everything. I just want to be notified about new commits, preferably major commits, like when there there's new security patches or a major update.

Could I do that?

If not, could I at least not get notified when someone opens an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. By default, the "Automatic Watching" setting is enabled/selected when you’re given push access to a repository.  This can be disabled by going to "Settings" from your account avatar, and then going to the "Notifications" tab.

[image: Github Account Settings]
[image: Notification settings]

2. In addition to the automatic watching, you can configure/disable the email notifications globally for your account, and by github organization.
3. To disable watch status on an individual Git repo, go to the repo page and click the "unwatch" button near the top of the page, and change the setting.

[image: Unwatch or ignore]

- Once you've disabled default watch settings on a git repo or for your
  entire account, you'll only receive notifications about new issues
  when someone manually tags you on the issue creation/comment.
- As for being notified only for "major commits", the best way to
  achieve that is to instruct code contributors to tag you on those
  specific "pull requests. You could also implement a policy/practice
  to prefix commit subjects or messages with release type (aka feature,
  bug, security update) to help filter commits better for review.

Comment: I just disabled `Comments on Issues and Pull Requests` while still watching a repo, would that stop the notifications coming every time someone's open an issue?

Comment: It should, as long as they don't tag you on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

"Release only" notifications were requested in 2015 on the unofficial github issue tracker:

> Ability to Watch a project but only for releases #410
>
> https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/410

Github finally released this feature this week:

https://help.github.com/articles/watching-and-unwatching-releases-for-a-repository/

[image: "Releases only" notifications]